# using PHP variables in a JavaScript function in a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

Simple question, but I still cant get my head around different languages being able to communicate with each other in a webpage!

I have a PHP section in my webpage, which links to an SQL database. It retrieves a column of postcode data and stores it in and array called `$info`.

I then have a javascript function which I want to be able to use the postcodes. How can I access the `$info` array (PHP) from the JavaScript? Does it have to go into some global array for all to see, or can the javascript access it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('<?php echo $myString; ?>');
</script>
```

It's the other way round that's hard.

PS: JavaScript != Java.

Comment: thanks! ps a simple, lazy typo, edited!